# How to open Excel after closing it through VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

While coding for an automation tool using VBA for Excel, I came across this situation. I have coded the "Close" command button as well as the "X" on the top-right of the form window. Both codes are same and serving their purpose.

I would like to know, if I close the workbook using the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` method in both the sub-procedures, then how to view the same Excel sheet's VBA project?

I am using Microsoft Office 2010.

Below is my code for reference:

```
Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)
If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
    MsgBox "Thanks for using! Tool will now close.", vbInformation + vbOKOnly
    Unload Me
    ActiveWorkbook.Close
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Basic for Applications lives in a *host*... application - here Microsoft Excel.

If you have 10 workbooks opened, the Visual Basic Editor (VBE) will have 10 VBA projects in your *Project Explorer* window (Ctrl+R); closing one, will remove its VBA project from the VBE - the VBA code *is* in that workbook you just closed!

There are two types of VBA projects: one is the *macro-enabled workbook* (.xlsm), the other is a *Microsoft Excel add-in* (.xlam). The former lives and dies with the *workbook* it's written in; the latter lives and dies with the *application* it's loaded in.

If you need code that can manage multiple workbooks, consider saving as (F12) an add-in; `ActiveWorkbook.Close` would close the *active workbook*, and then the add-in is still loaded... and you can still view its VBA source.

---

If you only mean to close a form, I suggest you don't implement the `QueryClose` handler, and let the form close by itself - *and leave the workbook open!*. <s>If you mean to close *another workbook*,</s> I strongly recommend you avoid `ActiveWorkbook` and use a `Workbook` object reference instead.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer Mat. If I leave the Workbook open, chances are that others would be able to see the code. I don't want that scenario. Any other possible ways?

Comment: I got a workaround. Thanks for the suggestion @Mat. I removed the `ActiveWorkbook.Close` method and secured the project with a password.

Comment: No problem. I'm still trying to see where in your question it was ever mentioned that the idea was to prevent users from seeing the code... next time try to be more specific about what you're trying to achieve and what problem you are attempting to solve, you may get better answers.

Comment: Sure @Mat. Thanks :) Sorry I missed to add it.